# Oracle userenv() alterative for snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

In oracle userenv('LANG') is used to get the language but not sure how to achieve the same in snowflake. tried select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'LANGUAGE') as well not working. please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the same thing as in Oracle, but Snowflake has a session parameter "LANGUAGE" applied to the current user's session.

You can get it as:

```sql
show parameters like 'LANGUAGE' in session;
```

Output:
[image]

if you need to extract just a value, you need to use the [result_scan method](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html) to select the desired column:

```sql
select $2 as LANGUAGE from table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you! but what is en ?

Comment: in my example it is a language tag in BCP-47 format for English